# How to set a default selection and value in dropdownlist with data from database?

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I have a dropdownlist with data loaded from MySQL database. The data.list was the list of data produced by a SQL query in node.js. Each record has a ID and a name. I want to set a default selection where the selected name is "John". The code below generates a dropdown where all options are selected instead of the option with name "John". Is there any way that I can achieve this by javascript? Thanks.

HTML Code with javascript:

```
        <select id="mySelect" name="mySel" size =20 multiple>
                <% if(data.list) { %>
                    <% data.list.forEach(function (row) { %>
                        <option value="<%= row.ID %>" <% row.name %> === "John" ? selected = true : false><%= row.name %></option>
                    <% }) %>
                <% } %>  
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with the following code:

```
type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mySel option:contains(John)").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the selected property is not well formed. The value true/false is incorrect. You just use selected or selected="selected"

good luck
Matias Creimerman

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I just use selected = "selected", all options will be selected, instead of the option with the name "John".